# Genetic diseases/conditions in Golden Retrievers

Tags: dogs, diseases, pet-selection, breeds, genetics

I'm not talking about conditions that the Golden Retriever is prone to develop in the future like cancer, but things like hip dysplasia that if the dog is guaranteed to inherit, may make it live in pain.

My questions are based on trying to find out which breeder to pick for getting my Golden Retriever. Because there appear to be the following types of breeders:

1. The excellent ones - they price their Retrievers at $4,000-4,500, but their Retrievers come with **no** genetic issues or conditions.
2. The good ones - they price their Retrievers between $2000-3000, their Retrievers come with **some** conditions like ichthyosis (dandruff skin problem) *or* their dam *or* sire - one of them alone tends to be carrier of some genetic condition like hip dysplasia, that make it a one in four chance that the puppy inherits it.
3. The poor ones - they shouldn't have bred their dam and sire in the first place, the dog is **guaranteed** to carry with it a severe neurologic condition because both their dam *and* sire have the neurologic condition.

I'm just curious about what to be worried about, and what I can over-look and this breed of dog can over-look without living in pain or having to put it down because the vet tells me it's suffering too much, and there are some like hip dysplasia that can cost up to $4,000 to get their hips replaced. Some conditions like heart murmurs, if I'm not wrong, are known to severely shorten the lifespan of the dog.

**Some sort of categorization of genetic conditions on this specific breed would help.**

Comment: This might not be what you want to hear, but if you want a healthy dog, your chances are much higher if you get a mixed breed. Purebreds always carry the risk of inbreeding, especially if the breeder often choses to breed with dogs in their close vicinity and doesn't track the family tree. That's what makes the "good" puppies so expensive: it's the work of finding a healthy, not related mate. A mixed breed has an extremely low chance of inbreeding and some health issues of one breed can be balanced out by the genetics of the second breed.

Comment: @Elmy Cost is not an issue for me as long as, 
1. I don't knowingly buy a dog that I'll have to put down because the vet told me "Didn't you know, she's been having this since birth", 
2. I don't knowingly sign up to watch it suffer.
3. I don't knowingly sign up to indirectly pay twice the cost of the dog in a lump sum to a vet surgeon to fix a problem

Comment: @Elmy From the looks of all this, I'm going to be paying 4500$

Comment: Be aware that getting the most expensive pet does not mean it will be free of health problems. Many health problems are acquired (not hereditary), even with the best breeding. Certainly you are encouraged to use a reputable breeder, but cost cost isn’t everything. The other day I saw a patient, a very expensive Ragdoll kitten; the breeders tested all their breeding cats for the hypertrophic cardiomyopathy mutation, yet this kitten unfortunately developed a serious genetic/developmental heart condition. That case is just bad luck, no fault of the breeder.

Comment: @HarryV. The breeder offers a life time health guarantee on the generic diseases alone. That's more than what ANY breeder I've looked for has ever offered